# Removing a different value from each column of a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following items

```
A<-data.frame(replicate(5,c(1,2,3,4)))
A=   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
     1  1  1  1  1
     2  2  2  2  2
     3  3  3  3  3
     4  4  4  4  4

B<-c(1,2,3,4,1)

B = 1 2 3 4 5
```

I want to find a way of removing the first element of B from the first column of A, the second element of B from the second column of A and so on so I obtain the following result

```
A=   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
     2  1  1  1  2
     3  3  2  2  3
     4  4  4  3  4
```

Comment: Can you guarantee this will not result in "ragged" `data.frame`? I.e. that each column with have the same number of elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `mapply` we can pass `A` and `B` in parallel and filter the values which are not present in `B`

```
mapply(function(x, y) x[x != y], A, B)

#     X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
#[1,]  2  1  1  1  2
#[2,]  3  3  2  2  3
#[3,]  4  4  4  3  4
```

PS - Make sure that `ncol(A)` and `length(B)` are the same otherwise it would lead to vector recycling giving some unexpected results.

Comment: Thanks - this is exactly what I was after!

Answer (score 1):

A `purrr` solution:

```
A<-data.frame(replicate(5,c(1,2,3,4)))
# X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
# 1  1  1  1  1  1
# 2  2  2  2  2  2
# 3  3  3  3  3  3
# 4  4  4  4  4  4

B<-c(1,2,3,4,1)
# [1] 1 2 3 4 1

purrr::map2_df(A, B, ~.x[.x != .y]) # function(x,y) x[x != y]

# # A tibble: 3 x 5
# X1    X2    X3    X4    X5
# <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     2     1     1     1     2
# 2     3     3     2     2     3
# 3     4     4     4     3     4
```